# Airflow DB session not providing any environement vabiable

Tags: python, airflow

As an Airflow and Python newbie, even don't know if I'm asking the right question, but asking anyway. 
I've configured airflow on a CentOS system. Use remote MySql instance as the backend. In my code, need to get a number of Variables, the code looks like below:

```
import os
from airflow.models import Variable

print(os.environ['SHELL'])
local_env['SHELL'] = Variable.get('SHELL')
```

And I got following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test2.py", line 5, in
>   
>       local_env['SHELL'] = Variable.get('SHELL')   File "/com/work/airflowenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py",
>   line 53, in wrapper
>       result = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/com/work/airflowenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py",
>   line 3134, in get
>       raise ValueError('Variable {} does not exist'.format(key)) ValueError: Variable SHELL does not exist

It is the Variable.get() method throws the exception in this piece of code in models.py:

```
    @classmethod
    @provide_session
    def get(cls, key, default_var=None, deserialize_json=False, session=None):
        obj = session.query(cls).filter(cls.key == key).first()
        if obj is None:
            if default_var is not None:
                return default_var
            else:
                raise ValueError('Variable {} does not exist'.format(key))
```

Where session.query already yield None. Don't quite understand how the session is injected here. and why these session variables not set. Should we set up something on the remote MySQL instance?

BTW, we have another identical airflow instance on another machine with local mysql instance. And running the script I provided stand alone has no problem:

> [2016-09-27 01:54:48,341] {**init**.py:36} INFO - Using executor
>
> LocalExecutor
>
> /bin/bash 
>   /bin/bash

Anything I missed when setting up the airflow? 
Thanks,

Comment: Hey, I figured out what is wrong, In the airflow backend database, there is an table called variable needs to be manually filled. Since I don't have this table filled upfront as bootstrapping step, query them yield me the empty data set.

Also, it would be nice if there is some API that I can fill the variable manually without initialize db again.

Since "variable" table is one of the default tables in the airflow backend database, we should be able to assign the variables when initialize the database. But I could not find it in any documents. Somebody can point me out where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally got the problem resolved. What I've done is print out the query, and figured out the variable must be from some relational database table called variable. And dig into the backend DB, found the DB, made the comparation between it and the working one, and figured out that the "variable" table data missed. 
The way to add these variable is simple: 
airflow variables -s SHELL /bin/bash
and so forth for other variables.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Variable model in Airflow has been used as a light weight key value store when Airflow db needed to be used to store some information.

If you want to store execution parameters, especially what looks like a static parameter, I would recommend having it as a params file in your DAG definition.